# Can you change the time when iCloud Backup takes place?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup

I have free data from midnight until 6AM and want backups to be done during this time to iCloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the time, but leaving an iPhone plugged in overnight will cause the iCloud Backup to start between 2:00 am and 4:00 am. iCloud Backup does not happen overnight if not connected to a Wi-Fi network, so free cellular data is a moot point.